# Facebook mentions not being returned

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am encountering an issue where non tagged posts created within the mentions section of a page are not being returned by the Facebook graph API.

We are currently using the endpoints below:

- ads_posts
- feed
- tagged

The app is also subscribed to the mentions webhook.

Has someone encountered the same issue?

Thanks
Vincent

We did a couple of tests by creating posts in the mentions section on our of our test pages but no webhook event at all.